# Hibernate ogm Neo4j entitymanager error

Tags: neo4j, entitymanager, hibernate-ogm

I'm trying to connect to Neo4j database. My database is downloaded from Neo4j site "Cineacts Actors &Movies". 
It located on C:\NewMovies

here comes my Application:

```
public class App 
{
    private static final String JBOSS_TM_CLASS_NAME = "com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager";
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {  
TransactionManager tm = getTransactionManager();
        //build the EntityManagerFactory as you would build in in Hibernate Core
      EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ogm-jpa-tutorial");
System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }

   public static TransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        try {
            Class<?> tmClass = App.class.getClassLoader().loadClass( JBOSS_TM_CLASS_NAME );
            return (TransactionManager) tmClass.getMethod( "transactionManager" ).invoke( null );
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch ( InvocationTargetException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch ( NoSuchMethodException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch ( IllegalAccessException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

my persistence file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="ogm-jpa-tutorial" transaction-type="JTA">
        <!-- Use Hibernate OGM provider: configuration will be transparent -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
        <class>com.mycompany.hibernateneo.Movie</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="neo4j_embedded" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.neo4j.database_path" value="C:/NewMovies" />

            <!-- defines which JTA Transaction we plan to use -->
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                      value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

my entity file:

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "Movie")
public class Movie {
   @Id
    String id;
    @Basic
    String title;
@Basic
    String description;
@Basic
    private String language;
@Basic
    private String imdbId;
@Basic
    private String tagline;
    @Basic
    private Integer runtime;
    @Basic
    private String homepage;
    @Basic
    private String trailer;
    @Basic
    private String genre;
    @Basic
    private String studio;
    @Basic
    private Integer version;
    @Basic
    private String imageUrl;
    public Movie() {
    }
    public Movie(String id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title=title;
    }
    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }
    public void setImdbId(String imdbId) {
        this.imdbId = imdbId;
    }
    public void setTagline(String tagline) {
        this.tagline = tagline;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public void setRuntime(Integer runtime) {
        this.runtime = runtime;
    }
    public void setHomepage(String homepage) {
        this.homepage = homepage;
    }
    public void setTrailer(String trailer) {
        this.trailer = trailer;
    }
    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }
    public void setStudio(String studio) {
        this.studio = studio;
    }
    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }
    public String getImdbId() {
        return imdbId;
    }
    public String getTagline() {
        return tagline;
    }
    public Integer getRuntime() {
        return runtime;
    }
    public String getHomepage() {
        return homepage;
    }
    public String getTrailer() {
        return trailer;
    }
    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }
    public String getStudio() {
        return studio;
    }
    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }
    public String getYoutubeId() {
        String trailerUrl = trailer;
        if (trailerUrl==null || !trailerUrl.contains("youtu")) return null;
        String[] parts = trailerUrl.split("[=/]");
        int numberOfParts = parts.length;
        return numberOfParts > 0 ? parts[numberOfParts-1] : null;
    }  
}
```

and error which I get:

Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: ogm-jpa-tutorial] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernateOgmPersistence.java:93)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at com.mycompany.hibernateneo.App.main(App.java:22)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.ogm.persister.SingleTableOgmEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:385)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.GridDialectFactory]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.impl.DatastoreServicesInitiator.initiateService(DatastoreServicesInitiator.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.impl.DatastoreServicesInitiator.initiateService(DatastoreServicesInitiator.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.persister.OgmEntityPersister.(OgmEntityPersister.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.persister.SingleTableOgmEntityPersister.(SingleTableOgmEntityPersister.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property hibernate.ogm.neo4j.database.path cannot be null
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.neo4j.impl.EmbeddedGraphDatabaseFactory.validate(EmbeddedGraphDatabaseFactory.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.neo4j.impl.EmbeddedGraphDatabaseFactory.initialize(EmbeddedGraphDatabaseFactory.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.neo4j.impl.Neo4jGraphDatabaseServiceFactoryProvider.load(Neo4jGraphDatabaseServiceFactoryProvider.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.neo4j.impl.Neo4jDatastoreProvider.configure(Neo4jDatastoreProvider.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmSessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(OgmSessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.GridDialectFactoryInitiator.createDialect(GridDialectFactoryInitiator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.GridDialectFactoryInitiator.initiateService(GridDialectFactoryInitiator.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.GridDialectFactoryInitiator.initiateService(GridDialectFactoryInitiator.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:176)
    ... 26 more

please, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
   <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                  value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform"/>
```

from the persistence.xml file. HibernateOGM for neo4j currently uses a workaround solution for transaction within OGM itself.

This is now reflected in the latest beta manual. [Look at the Warning box](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/4.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#_configuring_neo4j)